# What does color key's role in the image processing?

Tags: image, opengl, image-processing, opengl-es, opencv

I saw in some image processing software, we can specify "color key color", usally it is 255,0, 255 in RGB. what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`color key color` means the 'invisible' color. Or, by other words, the transparent one, like an alpha channel. Directly related to the Chroma key http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key
Also read this one http://www.saltw.net/index.php?topic=82117.0  part of the text named `Using Color Keying on 2D Sprites`

> What does this mean to you in this stage of computing? If you look
>   back at the last image of where we left off you would see there are
>   big white boxes that don't blend to the background. What we want from
>   the sprite is just the plane or the helishark. This problem existed
>   back then so one color in that 256 color pallete was called a Color
>   Key. This key when read by the computer would be understood to 'don't
>   draw this pixel, it is invisible.' It's still used today as it is a
>   very simple concept: If a pixel is this color, don't draw it!